# How to parse month string as Pandas Period

Tags: pandas, parsing, date

I have imported data as a Pandas DataFrame which has string representing months of various years such as: 'Nov-23', 'Mar-24' etc.
I would like to parse these strings into proper Pandas Periods. If I run (in September 2023):

```
>>> pd.Period.now('M')

Period('2023-09', 'M')
```

I get a Period object that seems to represent September in 2023 as expected. However, if I try:

```
>>> pd.Period('Sep-23', freq='M')

Period('1-09', 'M')
```

I do get a Period object seemingly representing September, but it seems to discard the information that it is in 2023.

How can I correctly parse time period strings like 'Sep-23' into Pandas Periods that retain their year?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not parsing it correctly

```
> pd.Period(pd.to_datetime('Sep-23',format="%b-%y"),freq='M')
Period('2023-09', 'M')
```